# Obter valores a partir de um arquivo de áudio

Tags: c, c++, áudio

Estou tentando usar uma biblioteca c++ para detectar frequencias de um som.
Para usa-la eu preciso passar um vetordo tipo double com os audio samples.
Eu consegui obter um vetor mas para isso tive que usar android para ele pegar audio do microfone ler em um double e gravar esse vetor em um arquvi txt.
Eu tenho já o arquivo no formato .wav.
Como que eu faço para pegar esse arquivo de audio, preenchendo um vetor double para eu passar para a função que faz a detecção das frequencias do audio sem usar android, com o proprio c++ ou até algum programa que faça isso?

Comment: Já existem várias bibliotecas tanto em C como C++ para isso. Pode consulta-las [aqui](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs)

Comment: pra que gravar isso em arquivo ? defina o vetor com um tamanho fixo, geralmente utilizo um tamanho de "4096", caminhe pelo seu arquivo de áudio a cada 4096 samples e envie o vetor preenchido para a sua função que detecta frequências, não precisa colocar nada em arquivo .txt

Comment: @ederwander existe alguma biblioteca que ja faça a leitura do .wav e me retorna o vetor do tipo double? Por exemplo, eu passo pra ele um arquivo .wav e e ele me retorna todos os samples  ou eu passo o audio e o numero de samples que eu quero que ele me retorne, algo desse tipo.

Comment: oi sim dá uma olhada nessa lib [link](https://mackron.github.io/dr_wav)